# How to access iphone music library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, audio-streaming

I want to open iphone music library of which is connected through wifi network.
How to do this ?

e.g. i have 2 iphones connected with each other through wifi. i want to open music library of other iphone.

Comment: +1 for interesting question and nearly -1 for unbelievable bad tagging.

Comment: have you access your own music library first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in solution for this. You'd have to write your own code for sharing files over Wi-Fi.